# MongoDB Find By Id returning "not found" even with the correct Id String

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to get an object from mongo db database and im passing the correct id as a String

Below is the code:

Controller:

```
 /**
     * Receive an OfertaEspecial Id and generates a Voucher for each Destinatario .
     */
    @PostMapping("{id}")
    public void generateVoucher(@PathVariable String id) {
        voucherService.generateVoucher(id);
    }
```

Service:

```
  public void generateVoucher(String id) {

        //Get the oferta especial by id and check if it exists in the database. If it does not exist, throw an exception.
        OfertaEspecial ofertaEspecial = ofertaEspecialRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Oferta especial not found"));
          ....
```

Heres the image from the database
[image]

Im passing the exaclty same id on the request as you can see here:

[image]

The log error below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Oferta especial not found
    at com.launchersoft.vouchersapi.service.VoucherService.lambda$generateVoucher$0(VoucherService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    > ~\[na:na\]    at
    > java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~\[na:na\]][3]][3]
```

I tried to convert to Object id , however the method only accept String.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more code pls? The entity and the repository to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just solved removing the id from my model:

@Document(collection = "ofertas_especiais")
@Data
@Builder
public class OfertaEspecial {

```
private String Id;
private String nome;
private double percentage;
private String descricao;
private LocalDate dataValidade;
```

}

And them started wortk again. But the error message about mapping is still showing.